# asyncStorage not working properly while submitting the data to the server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using asyncStorage and testing in android emulator. Below is the code.

```
 postData() {
  this.setData();
  const address = this.getData();
  fetch('https://url/post/data',{
    'method' : 'POST',
    'body':JSON.stringify({
            param1:"123",
            param2: "121",
            param3: "122",
            city: address
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Complete')      
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  });

}

setData() {
const city = 'bangalore';
AsyncStorage.setItem('address', city)
  .then(json => console.log('success!'))
  .catch(error => console.log('error!'));
}

getData() {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem('address');
}
```

On the server POST (I am using PHP), I am receiving the following 
incorrect data for "city"

```
        [city] => Array\n(\n
        [_40] => 0\n
        [_65] => 0\n
        [_55] => \n
        [_72] => \n)\n\n)\n
```

Please suggest me what went wrong.

Thanks, 
Raja K

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage is (as the name implies) asynchronous, so when you execute your post fetch request the address variable is still a Promise object. The strange data you are receiving in the backend is the representation of that Promise.

You can easily fix this by adding an extra .then() clause:

```
postData() {
  this.setData();
  this.getData().then(address) => 
    fetch('https://url/post/data',{
      'method' : 'POST',

  ...

)}
```